# How to control 12V from 5V using transistor?

Tags: power-supply, transistors, relay, switch-mode-power-supply, switching

[image]i have used BC547 Transistor to stepup from 4.6v but I can't able to draw above 5v from collector, I have given input of 4.6v to base and emitter to ground and collector to output load. but load doesn't activate. Can anyone help me out from this problem?

Comment: You need to add a schematic to your question so we can all see how you have connected the transistor and load.

Comment: I have upadated my question, please check it out!

Comment: Your wording is strange, you're  not "stepping up", instead you want to use a signal from a uC to switch on/off an NPN which will turn on/off a relay. The relay contacts supply 12 V power to a load. The circuit has issues, there's no flyback diode so the NPN will be damaged when it switches off the relay. There's no reason to draw a thick wire around the relay, just flip the relay upside down and the wire to 12 V can be much shorter. Then draw the load also in the schematic.

Comment: Sorry i have added diode in the circuit but i forgot to add it in the schematic!

Comment: Have you checked it with a 5V source, without the µC? Does it work then?

Comment: No, But I checked transistor voltages when ever the signal receives. it is like at base it is 4.6v and at emitter and collector it is 3.6v , but the operating voltage of relay is more than 6v.

Comment: If the transistor has an emitter voltage of 3.6V against ground, the emitter isn't grounded properly. That's the problem.

Comment: As others have said - you show the emitter connected to ground (as it should be) SO the emitter MUST be AT ground potential. It CANNOT be at 3.6V. Why do you say that it is?

Answer (score 5):

You need a diode across the relay coil to handle back EMF or you may destroy the transistor. Ignore the LED in this picture

[image]

Comment: @yashwanth moparthi: Dirk is right, the only thing wrong in your schematic is the missing diode. The relay may have shot your transistor dead on first turnoff.

Comment: Instead of "may damage" you can safely write "will damage" the transistor. Never skip the diode ! (D1 in this schematic).

Comment: @Dirk Bruere : thanks for your schematic , the thing here is i have already added flyback diode but i didn't drawn it in my schematic.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a logic level mosfet like IR530n to control 12V source with only 5v of Microcontroller or arduino

Here is the circuit, but the values should be calculated to adapte your circuit.

This configuration is called low side drive

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fSRnnf.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>